# NSFetchedResultsController depth of fetchedObjects

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have a strange problem here and I want to know, if its related to the lazy loading function.
I do a fetch on my categories. Imagine they have subcategories and these have subsubcategories also. the question right now is: Is the fetchedObjects-Array also collecting the data of the relationship from the subcategories. In short, is it possible to access data something like that: category.subcategory.subsubcategory.name or do i need to make a new fetch on the subcategories first to get access like with subcategory.subsubcategory.name?

I dont get the whole set of the subsubcategories while I am doing it with one fetch. i only get everytime 1 entry instead of 20 or whatever the count should be.

Does anyone have an idea how coredata is handling this? And is it the common way to make a fetchrequest on every new table? Wouldn't it be quite inefficient?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Use `setIncludesSubentities` on the NSFetchRequest.

you can also use `setPropertiesToFetch` to go deep like `category.subcategory.subsubcategory.name`

propertiesToFetch I believe only works on attributes and to-one relationships however...